# Prettify MongoDb ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, objectid

We are developing photo gallery which is storing huge amount of photos. We have choosed MongoDB's GridFS for image storage. Every thing looks fine.

But every time when user has to delete the photo we thought of deleting particular photo based on its `"ObjectId"`, but Sending ObjectId to client side looks ugly because of its length. Deleting based on photo name is not possible because its not unique.

So how do we `prettify` the `ObjectId` to send it to client side?

Comment: "looks ugly" to whom?

Comment: you could, for instance, devise an algorithm that has similar low collision probability while at the same time guaranteeing prettyness. Your gravatar icon is a pretty version of the hash of your email. You could turn that around and upload a picture every time instead of using an id... No, to be honest: why would the user even *see* the id? Shouldn't that be an ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this belongs as an answer since it's subjective, but then again, so is the question:

If you want to not involve another field, you can change the encoding of the id. I think base64 looks just fine:

`55036ee50202b73c1a021897` -> `NTUwMzZlZTUwMjAyYjczYzFhMDIxODk3`

Another option is to generate a random string and store it on the document, which gives you a lot of customizability in the appearance. For example, you could do 4 digit codes with only upper-case characters like `BUZQ`. However, be sure to create a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) so you don't accidentally create duplicate identifiers.